# Как сделать отображение команд бота при нажатии "/" Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

> Мы ввели новые слэш-команды для ботов. Взаимодействовать с ботами
> стало ещё проще. Теперь разработчики могут создать список команд для
> ботов, который будет отображаться по нажатию кнопки «/». Вам больше не
> придётся запоминать команды для ботов и краснеть, когда вы будете
> ошибаться :( !help... !help... да помогите уже кто-нибудь…

Вот что написано в обновлении, но никакой ссылки на документацию как это делать я не нашёл.

p.s
я про это меню
[image: меню]

Comment: По _нажатию_ никак нельзя. Может имеете в виду типа команду?

Comment: Документация по slash-commands: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#slash-commands-interactions-and-bot-users